# CakePHP: creating fixtures for aliased tables

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

I am using a table to store optional data about a number of different types of objects. Thus the table has the following structure:

```sql
create table options
(
    id           int auto_increment
        primary key,
    object_id    int          not null,
    object_model varchar(255) not null,
    option_name  varchar(255) not null,
    option_value text         null,
    created      datetime     not null,
    modified     datetime     not null
);

create index object_model
    on options (object_model);
```

Optional values are found by a combination of both the ID of the object to look up and by the model from which that object comes. Here is how an example model, my Images model, uses it:

```php
$this->hasMany('ImageOptions', [
     'foreignKey' => 'object_id',
     'className' => 'Options',
     'dependent' => true,
])->setConditions(['ImageOptions.object_model LIKE' => $this->getAlias()]);
```

This system has worked fine for me in the past, but now that I'm running PHPUnit on my application, there seems to be some confusion. When saving a new image with metadata to save to this table, I get the message:

```php
1) Visualize\Test\TestCase\Controller\ImagesControllerTest::testAddSubmit
Possibly related to Cake\Database\Exception: "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'visualize_test.options' doesn't exist"
```

I can assure you that the table is there and works fine. I'm able to browse the page with no such error messages and even submit a new image without incident. But not in the test.

I assume this has something to do with the aliasing of the database table, but I'm unsure how to resolve it or work around it? Thanks in advance for the help!

Here also is my fixture for ImageOptions:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Visualize\Test\Fixture;

use Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture;

/**
 * OptionsFixture
 */
class ImageOptionsFixture extends TestFixture
{
    /**
     * Table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $table = 'options';

    /**
     * Fields
     *
     * @var array
     */
    // phpcs:disable
    public $fields = [
        'id' => ['type' => 'integer', 'length' => null, 'unsigned' => false, 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'comment' => '', 'autoIncrement' => true, 'precision' => null],
        'object_id' => ['type' => 'integer', 'length' => null, 'unsigned' => false, 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'comment' => '', 'precision' => null, 'autoIncrement' => null],
        'object_model' => ['type' => 'string', 'length' => 255, 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'collate' => 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', 'comment' => '', 'precision' => null],
        'option_name' => ['type' => 'string', 'length' => 255, 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'collate' => 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', 'comment' => '', 'precision' => null],
        'option_value' => ['type' => 'text', 'length' => null, 'null' => true, 'default' => null, 'collate' => 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', 'comment' => '', 'precision' => null],
        'created' => ['type' => 'datetime', 'length' => null, 'precision' => null, 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'comment' => ''],
        'modified' => ['type' => 'datetime', 'length' => null, 'precision' => null, 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'comment' => ''],
        '_indexes' => [
            'object_model' => ['type' => 'index', 'columns' => ['object_model'], 'length' => []],
        ],
        '_constraints' => [
            'primary' => ['type' => 'primary', 'columns' => ['id'], 'length' => []],
        ],
        '_options' => [
            'engine' => 'InnoDB',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
        ],
    ];
    // phpcs:enable
    /**
     * Init method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function init(): void
    {
        $this->records = [
            [
                'id' => 4,
                'object_id' => 1,
                'object_model' => 'Images',
                'option_name' => 'this_value',
                'option_value' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliquet feugiat.',
                'created' => '2021-09-03 10:34:42',
                'modified' => '2021-09-03 10:34:42',
            ],
            [
                'id' => 5,
                'object_id' => 1,
                'object_model' => 'Images',
                'option_name' => 'that_value',
                'option_value' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliquet feugiat.',
                'created' => '2021-09-03 10:34:42',
                'modified' => '2021-09-03 10:34:42',
            ],
            [
                'id' => 6,
                'object_id' => 1,
                'object_model' => 'Images',
                'option_name' => 'the_other_value',
                'option_value' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliquet feugiat.',
                'created' => '2021-09-03 10:34:42',
                'modified' => '2021-09-03 10:34:42',
            ]
        ];
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

And an example of one test which is failing is here:

Comment: How is browsing your application related to the testing environment? Certainly you're not running tests against your production database?

Comment: No. I mean that I can access my development version of the site fine. Usually if there's an actual data or model configuration issue, I would be able to see it in the browser, but in this case that is not happening.

Comment: I should further explain that the database tables are all being created using migrations, so everything about the database is also defined in the PHP: there should be no difference between the database being used in development and that being created in testing.

Comment: You'll have to provide some more details as to where/how you run migrations in your test environment, and how you've configured phpunit, as there is no standardized way in the core yet for migrations in the test environment, the default for now are still [**fixtures**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html#fixtures).

Comment: Yes, I'm using fixtures. So right off the bat, I'm closer to the problem. I've just created a fixture that matches the OptionsFixture that got automatically generated when I created the table, named ImageOptionsFixture. But that still doesn't change the result.

Comment: Have you **[loaded](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html#loading-fixtures-in-your-test-cases)** the fixture in your test case?

Comment: Yes, it's loaded. It is interesting that it sees the table name as "options" when the fixture is classed as ImageOptions?

Comment: By default it would `image_options`, however since your table is called `options`, I would've expected that you've set the table name in the fixture class accordingly. It would help if you'd show your actual test case / fixture code.

Comment: Ok, so it seems clear to me that I don't understand how to create test fixtures for aliased tables. Perhaps that ought to be the title of this post (will update). Where do I set the table name in a fixture? i don't see it in the default baked fixture?

Comment: In their `$table` property.

Comment: Excellent. And if, as in the case of my association, there are conditions by which the association is made, is there a place to add that? Under constraints? Thanks so much for the help! This isn't documented anywhere I can find it.

Comment: Association conditions are for filtering when querying data, what would they do in fixtures?

Comment: Perhaps nothing. But the tests aren't working? To reiterate: when running tests on aliased Models, it's telling me that the table itself cannot be found (see the original post). I'm just trying to figure out why that might be?